# One liner to convert small text string to PDF

Tags: command-line, bash, software-recommendation, pdf, text

I've been trying to find a way to create a simple PDF page from the terminal that contains only one string, for example, "Prelude".

Some background: I use pdfunite to join music charts together into a single PDF. Here's an example:

```
 pdfunite Welcome.pdf Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ChildrensPrayer.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf ~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf
```

What I am trying to find is a way to create custom sheets in the final PDF all in one single command, similar to this:

```
pdfunite Welcome.pdf (enscript "Have a seat" - | ps2pdf - output.pdf) Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf ~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf
```

In essence, creating a PDF that contains text "Have a seat" on the fly and inserting it into the correct spot of the final document.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tl;dr

`pdfunite` may error out in case the file descriptor containing the standard output of the command running inside the command substitution is empty by the time it's read.

So you're better off using an alternative to `pdfunite`; since you have `ghostscript` installed you could use `gs`:

```bsh
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf Welcome.pdf <(enscript <<<"echo foo" -p -) Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf
```

---

If I understood correctly you were pretty close:

```bsh
pdfunite Welcome.pdf <(enscript <<<"Have a seat" -p - | ps2pdf - -) Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf ~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf
```

The `<<<"Have a seat"` token in the `enscript` command will redirect `enscript`'s standard input to the string and the `-p -` token will make the `enscript` command print to standard output;

Using `<()` instead of `()` will make the whole `<()` token be replaced with the file descriptor containing the standard output of the command running inside `<()` (AKA process substitution), using `-` instead of `output.pdf` will make `ps2pdf` print the PDF to standard output instead of to a file.

But the problem with this approach is that **`pdfunite` may error out in case the file descriptor containing the standard output of the command running inside the command substitution is empty by the time it's read**.

So you're better off using an alternative to `pdfunite`; since you have `ghostscript` installed you could use `gs`:

```bsh
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf Welcome.pdf <(enscript <<<"echo foo" -p -) Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf
```

```
% enscript <<<"foo" -p -  | ps2pdf - foo.pdf 
[ 1 page * 1 copy ] left in -
% gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=foobar.pdf foo.pdf <(enscript <<<"bar" -p -)
[ 1 page * 1 copy ] left in -
GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Loading NimbusMon-Bol font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/Font/NimbusMon-Bol... 4726404 3142423 2470576 1091522 3 done.
Loading NimbusMon-Reg font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/Font/NimbusMon-Reg... 4759732 3269347 2490768 1100127 3 done.
%
```

`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=foobar.pdf foo.pdf <(enscript <<<"bar" -p -)` correctly chains `foo.pdf` and a document containing the word "bar" generated via the PostScript script generated by `enscript <<<"bar" -p -`.

Comment: Thanks! But no luck-- I think the issue may be in how I'm using enscript-- it gives some errors, like can't open input file 'have a seat', etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JasonSilver Yes, there were problems also in your call to `enscript`, see the edit for clarifications: `pdfunite Welcome.pdf <(enscript <<<"Have a seat" -p - | ps2pdf - -) Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf ~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf`.

Comment: Still receiving an error:`[ 1 page * 1 copy ] left in -
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Error: Could not merge damaged documents ('/dev/fd/63')`

Comment: If I run this standalone: ` <<<"Have a seat" -p - | ps2pdf - ~/Desktop/test.pdf` then I get and error that -p: command not found, and it creates a blank pdf.

Comment: @JasonSilver I see, the problem is that `pdfunite` tries to read from the file descriptor before it contains the document. Perhaps this can be solved with some Bash hackery, but since you have `ghostscript` installed you could use a totally different approach, : `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=~/Desktop/2016-03-12.pdf Welcome.pdf <(enscript <<<"echo foo" -p -) Rooftops.pdf Announcements.pdf ComeAliveDryBones.pdf Benediction.pdf Dismissal.pdf`.

Comment: Wow, that's great, but not as simple/elegant as pdfunite. I wonder if there's a way to get pdfunite to wait for enscript to finish? I suppose you would have suggested it if there were. I'll play around with a bash script that uses Ghostscript but behaves like pdfunite. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JasonSilver No problem. Anyway I suppose that'd be a matter of opinions, but I find to use `gs` to be more elegant than to use `pdfunite` in this case: `gs` processes the PostScript script directly (and hence it takes out the need of passing it to `ps2pdf` beforehand), so technically using `gs` is one step less to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @kos I don't get why that is a problem. Appending empty files to another file makes no sense. I assume that's not the case. Just a curious party. Have fun!

Comment: @user3005629 Bear with me, what is "that" exactly?

Comment: What he is trying to do with Python I mean, I still haven't learned Python just fiddle with it but still I don't think he is trying to append content from an empty source. It is possible to do but could be a very particular functionality to be in a standard library or generic piece of code.

Comment: @user3005629 I'm having a hard time understanding your query. I'm not sure why you're referencing Python or empty files, no one ever even mentioned Python so far, could you clarify?

Comment: @kos Wow yes total blunder! Then my mention of appending falls in Bash but I haven't used the less than sign that could just be an inversion. Good thing to ask DuckDuckgo. Then let me check again the script and get back.

Comment: I did some research and got to Pandoc : https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37306/discussion-between-user3005629-and-kos).

Comment: If I wanted to insert a newline within a string sent to gs, how would I do that? This doesn't work:  gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=out.pdf  <(enscript <<<"First Line\nNextLine\nLast Line" -p - --no-header  --font=Times25 --margins=20:20:200:0 )

Answer (score 2):

I needed to create a small PDF file with page size just matching the text, ie a little label-sized PDF. I think that objective matches the question as stated. In one line, this can be done as follows:

`echo "foobar" | enscript --no-header -p out.ps && ps2pdf out.ps && pdfcrop out.pdf out.pdf`

This results in a little file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It works. Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

*I feel badly not accepting the answer suggested by @kos but I could not get it to work, and I preferred to continue with the simplicity of pdfunite. @kos helped me to understand enscript (THANKS!)*

My final solution was to write a bash script to create the temporary PDF files, then string them together using pdfunite.

The command is issued as follows:

```
./charts.bash -o=output-filename.pdf ./AlmostThere.pdf ./Breathe.pdf -c="The Gospel According to Matthew" ./Doxology.pdf -c="Closing Prayer"
```

Here's the bash script (I'm a novice, go easy)

```
#!/bin/bash
CHARTS=()
DELETEAFTER=()
for i in "$@"
do
    case $i in
        -o=*|--output=*)
        OUTPUT="${i#*=}"
    ;;
        -c=*|--create=*)
        NEWFILENAME="${i#*=}"
        NEWFILENAME=${HOME}/Desktop/${NEWFILENAME//[[:space:]]/}.pdf
        enscript <<<"${i#*=}" -p - --no-header --font=Courier25 --margins=20:20:200:0 | ps2pdf - $NEWFILENAME
        CHARTS+=("$NEWFILENAME")
    ;;
        *)
         # unknown option
        CHARTS+=("${i#*=}")
        DELETEAFTER+=("$NEWFILENAME");
    ;;
    esac
done
pdfuniteString=$(printf " %s" "${CHARTS[@]}")
pdfuniteString=${pdfuniteString:1}
wait
pdfunite $pdfuniteString ${HOME}/Desktop/${OUTPUT}
wait
for i in "${DELETEAFTER[@]}"
do
    if [ -n "$i" ]; then
        rm "$i"
    fi
done
echo Complete
```